# Why there is no std::move_if_noexcept counterpart for std::forward in C++11/14?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, noexcept

I have watched Scott Meyers' talk on GoingNative2013 "An Effective C++11/14 Sampler" and he explained the use of `std::move_if_noexcept`.

So in my opinion there should be a `std::forward_if_noexcept` to also guarantee exception-safety for `forward`? Why is there nothing like this in the Standard Library? Is there another possibility to guarantee it?

Comment: There's no point in restoring or preserving an rvalue. That doesn't mean that there aren't use cases for such a helper, though.

Comment: What would the semantics of `forward_if_noexcept` be? I.e., compared to `move_if_noexcept`?

Comment: *"to also guarantee exception-safety for `forward`"* I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. `move_if_noexcept` doesn't have any more or less exception safety guarantees than `move`: it's `noexcept`, just a cast. `move_if_noexcept` is useful to preserve objects, i.e. being able to restore a former state if moving can fail.

Comment: Niall, forward is able to handle universal references, so with the collapsing rules, if i use a Templatefunction with Typededuction and T&&, and i call it with a rvalue -> it will move, if i call it with a lvalue -> it will copy. So in my opinion forward_if_noexcept should extend forward to copy if theres no noexcept, else the old behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminSchmidt, interesting question and rationale.

Comment: @dyp what i meant by a guarantee of exception-safety is strong exception safety (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety)

so if a couple of moves fail at some point (exception), you cannot roll back to the initial state of data. This safety is given by `move_if_noexcept`, because it checks if the Type of object is noexcept(true). If it's true -> move is safe and will be performed, if it's false -> copy will be performed to guarantee a rollback

Comment: @BenjaminSchmidt Ok, then my first comment applies: it's not as useful to restore the state of an rvalue as it is to restore the state of an lvalue (one might even argue that it's not useful at all).

Answer (score 7):

The forward semantics already are conditional, i.e., they preserve the value category of its argument. The move, on the other hand, unconditionally changes (from an l-value to r-value) the value category of its argument to an r-value (reference), the `std::move_if_noexcept` obtains the resultant value category based on whether or not the move constructor throws no exceptions, effectively also making it conditional.

In short, **`std::forward` doesn't change anything**, it preserves the value category. `std::move` on the other hand, does change the value category. So **`std::move_if_noexcept` is introduced to say that if `std::move`'s change could cause an exception, then don't change anything**; don't move it.

I think the rationale here also goes to the intended idiomatic use of all things `std::move` and `std::forward` respectively. In one of Scott's other talks (possibly at C++ and Beyond 2012) on "universal references", forwarding and moving, he was quite emphatic on the idiomatic use of forward, and I think this underpins a lot of what `std::forward` is and how it is used. It may also just be as simple as it was never considered.

I would argue that there is no need, or at least there is diminished need when the `std::forward` is effected.

Given that there may be a use case for it, implementing one would not be too hard; but I'm not sure as to the general use case. It could be argued that the conditions related to the possible exceptions, and the required exception guarantees, should be **tested for and dealt with outside of the function doing the forwarding**.

```
template <class U, class T>
U wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    return U(forward<T>(arg));
}

template <class U, class T>
U method() 
{
  T t;
  // work with t
  return wrapper<U>(move_if_noexcept(t));
}
```

Granted, it is "early days" for a lot of this, so that may change.

Comment: correct me if i'm false, but the condition of `std::forward` doesn't check for `noexcept`, so i thought it would call `std::move` if the param is a rvalue, and so there's no preservation?

Comment: @BenjaminSchmidt, I'm not aware of any checks wrt `noexcept`, but `forward` doesn't actually call `move`, it's just a `static_cast` (as `move` is) with some error checks on the arguments and types

Comment: you're right, i used the "call of move" just as an methodology to visualize what happens when forward is called, the actual implementation is different and surely more efficient

Comment: @BenjaminSchmidt, I can't remember if it was that talk or another one Scott have on forwarding and moving, but he was quite emphatic on the idiomatic use of forward, and I think this underpins a lot of what forward is and is used how it is.

Comment: i think this was in C++ and Beyond 2012, i refer to http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler

at 19:52 he explained the behavior of `std::forward`
 with a piece of example code ( like me with a call of move :o) )